# merging multiple csv files in R using do.call

Tags: r, merge, do.call

I am trying to import and merge a set of csv files using the following code, but it doesn't seem to be passing the by=c("X","Y") argument to the merge function. Any recommendations on how to fix this? Thank you

```
csvfiles <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='bbg_.*\\.csv$')
csvfiles <- paste("fx/",csvfiles,sep="")
csvfiles

my.df <- do.call("merge",list(lapply(csvfiles, read.csv, header = TRUE), by=c("date","fx_code")))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`merge` doesn't accept more than 2 data.frames, so you can't pass it a larger list using `do.call`:

```
do.call(merge, list(iris, iris, iris))
#Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
#  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

Use `Reduce` instead:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Species"), list(iris, iris, iris))
#works
```

Comment: thanks very much - that worked. i used 

                 
    import.list <- lapply(csvfiles, read.csv, header = TRUE)

    my.df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=FALSE,by=c("fx_code","date"),all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE),import.list,accumulate=F)

Answer (score 3):

`do.call` accepts a list of *all* arguments, so try:

```
my.df <- do.call("merge",append(lapply(csvfiles, read.csv, header = TRUE), list(by=c("date","fx_code")) )
```