Reducing length of several data frames in R based on common values of one variable
I am working with 11 different data frames in R, each with several columns of data on U.S. counties. Each observation, therefore, pertains to one county. The data frames are of different lengths, indicating that some data frames have entries for counties that other data frames do not. All data frames have a "FIPS" code as the value in one column, which indicates which U.S. county the observation gives data on. I want to reduce the length of all 11 data frames to identical lengths, with identical vectors of FIPS codes.
To illustrate, two data frames are called "Gini" and "Crime2022." I used this code to reduce them to common lengths:
Gini1 <- Gini[Gini$FIPS %in% c(Crime2018$FIPS) , ]

Crime2018_1 <- Crime2018[Crime2018$FIPS %in% c(Gini$FIPS) , ]

This worked, but with 11 data frames, there will be many iterations of this code. Is there an easier way? I got help on a similar problem, but it dealt with different data frames of very similar names. Here is that code:
CrimeAll <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    2018:2022, \(yr)
      within(get(paste0("Crime", yr)), { year <- yr })
  )
)

# ASSIGN AND SUBSET COUNTIES IN ALL 5 YEARS
CrimeAll <- within(
  CrimeAll, { county_n <- ave(year, FIPS, FUN=length) }
) |> subset(
  subset = county_n == 5, select = -county_n
)

# BUILD LIST OF YEAR SPLIT DATA FRAMES
CrimeList <- split(CrimeAll, CrimeAll$year)

CrimeList$`2018`
CrimeList$`2019`
...
CrimeList$`2022`

Can I do the same with data frames with non-similar names (i.e. "Crime2018", "Gini", "S1901Income2018", and "S1903Income2018"?

Your question is neither reproducible nor minimal. I think you are looking for a variant of Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list.of.data.frames) but this is hard to tell

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644983/1412059

I've created some random sample data here using the data frame names you supplied.
My approach is to:

create a list of all the data frames
use Reduce() on this list to create a vector with the FIPS codes common to all data frames
use this vector to subset each data frame in the list

# Create some sample data
set.seed(123)
Crime2018 <- data.frame(FIPS = sample(letters, 22), value1 = runif(22, 1, 50))
Gini <- data.frame(FIPS = sample(letters, 22), value2 = runif(22, 1, 50))
S1901Income2018 <- data.frame(FIPS = sample(letters, 22), value3 = runif(22, 1, 50))
S1903Income2018 <- data.frame(FIPS = sample(letters, 22), value4 = runif(22, 1, 50))



# create a vector of data frame names
my_names <- c("Crime2018", "Gini", "S1901Income2018", "S1903Income2018")
# use this to create a named list of the data frames
list_of_dfs <- setNames(
  lapply(my_names, get),
  my_names
)

# create a vector with the common values of FIPS
common_fips <- Reduce(
  intersect, 
  lapply(list_of_dfs, \(x) x$FIPS)
)

# create subset of only the common rows of each data frame in the list
new_dfs <- lapply(list_of_dfs, function(x) x[x$FIPS %in% common_fips, ])

Created on 2024-06-17 with reprex v2.1.0

This worked! Thank you very much!
